# Why does Djikstra's algorithm need to keep track of the number of steps?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I can understand keeping track of the accumulated distance, the distance per path, and keeping track of the name (or position) of the vertex, but why keep track of the number of steps unless you are wanting to track how efficiently it reached its destination?

The step is totally unnecessary for finding the path, and it seems rather arbitrary anyway.  For instance, if you have multiple vertices where the accumulated distance is the same, and the smallest number, there is no reason to care which one you start from, but whichever one it is gets labelled with the next step in line.

I see many pieces of code around, and they generally follow this principle of keeping track of the steps.  It seems very strange, especially when many of them are pathfinding on a 2D matrix where the cost of movement is either 1 or infinite.  In that case, it seems to me that not only is the number of steps per vertex superfluous, but the only information necessary to be bothered with is the distance and the label of the vertex.  If you have a distance, you know you have visited the vertex, and since all distances are the same, the first time you reach a vertex should always be its lowest distance.  No evaluating whether it is lower or greater is necessary, only that it exists.

Anyway, I'm just curious why something so simple should have superfluous information gathered.  Is there some reason for it I'm just not grasping?

EDIT--

To add a little clarity, and since it wasn't formatting properly in the comment, the step is normally shown in the table people tell you to use.

```
____________________
|name|step|distance|
--------------------
|temporary Labels  |
--------------------
```

The step is added when a position is the next shortest point to the origin.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with “the number of steps”?

Comment: Normally, it is represented as a table.

`|name|step|distance|`
`|temporary labels  |`

Comment: So is that the parent/previous node, or what exactly? What is a possible value for a “step”? I’m sorry but I don’t recognize that at all (and I never used such a table either…).

Comment: There's no need to keep track of the number of steps when you also track the distance. When step cost is always unit or infinite, tracking the number of steps is equivalent to tracking distance covered.

Comment: That table is everywhere.  You can't look up Djikstra's algorithm without running into it.  Here's a Youtube video queued up to the point where they start showing it.  This one is different in that they don't have a box for the name of the vertex, as they are provided outside the table.

(http://youtu.be/xT5o1QCeWS8?t=3m11s)

The step is essentially the number of steps before you checked a vertex's connections.  It is not the distance, unless you go in a straight line and there are no other non-infinite vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I have seen that video now and it’s actually the first time I have ever seen such a table being used. It does not make much sense to me. It completely mixes “labels” with “distances”; a permanent label is the order in which nodes were marked, while temporary labels are the current non-fixed distances. Neither of these are necessary at all.

Instead what you usually have for a node is the following: The **distance** (from the start node), the **parent** (or previous) node, and a **mark** to mark a node as completed or not (in an implementation you usually have a priority queue for all unmarked nodes instead).

You then keep looking at the unmarked node with the smallest total distance, mark it and update the distance of all the unmarked neighbors. And whenever you update to a shorter distance you also update the parent node.

In no way though you need to have the order in which you marked the nodes as completed or have all the previous uncomplete distances. To me, in that video, it seems as if it’s just a way to make it easier to check a student’s work, as without identical distances you always have a single order in which you would look at the vertices.

That being said, the normal [Dijkstra algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Algorithm) does not include this stuff, and it’s not necessary. See the [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode) on Wikipedia for implementation details on what you actually store (as said, you usually have only the distance and parent for each node, and a priority queue for the unmarked nodes).

> It seems very strange, especially when many of them are pathfinding on a 2D matrix where the cost of movement is either 1 or infinite.

What you are describing here is a very special case. The Dijkstra algorithm is actually used for many graph problems where distances are *not* equal, and with more connections that just 4 simple neighbors in every direction.

Comment: Well, I've seen that little table, or one very similar, many times.  It was even in one of my textbooks.  I didn't pay too much attention then.  It was just homework to me.

My thought is that it has been used as a teaching tool, and finding it in code is an artifact of that.

I just wanted to make sure there wasn't something I was overlooking.

Thanks.